# How to explicitly tell Proguard to remove full package?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have these rules to skip all activities and fragments:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

What I want is to remove all the unused classes that rely on an activity (which is removed from Manifest) called ProductActivity.

I have these rules on Proguard file:

```
-keep class !com.alouane.app.product.** { *; }
-keep class !com.alouane.app.products.** { *; }
```

But it doesn't seem to be working when analysing the APK.

[full proguard file](https://gist.github.com/alouanemed/f211500e23b5cb97b2b3f4fac2bbf61d)

Comment: Don't know if the order of the proguard config matters, but in case it does, maybe it does help to put `-keep class !com.alouane.app.product.** { *; }` above the other general `--keep ...` lines.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use -injars with filter, I am using proguard maven plugin, and below configuaration in pom.xml works

> `<inFilter>!com/alouane/app/product/**.class</inFilter>`

I am not sure about your build process however I guess something like below should work

> -injars  myAppJar.jar(!com.alouane.app.product.**)

or

> -injars  myAppJar.jar(!!com/alouane/app/product/**.class)